# Variables and memory allocated for them?

Tags: python, memory

I have a question about Python deal with memory to copy variables.

For example, I have a list(or string, tuple, dictionary, set) variable

```
A = [1,2,3]
```

then I assign the value of A  to another variable B

```
B = A
```

then if I do "some changes" to A, e.g.,

```
A.pop(0)
```

then B also changes, i.e.,
print(A,B) will give me ([2,3], [2,3])

I read some material and they say "B=A did not copy the value of A to a new place in memory labelled by B. It just made the name B point to the same position in memory as A." Can I interpret this as we still only have one place of memory, but now it has 2 names?

However, I found that if I did some other changes to A, such as

```
A = [5,6]  # I reassign A value,
```

Then I found
    print(A,B)
gives me ([5,6],[1,2,3])

So I am confused here. It seems that now we have two places of memory

Comment: I remember finding it helpful to think of variable assignment as attaching sticky notes to things. So when you use `B = A` you have two sticky notes A and B attached to the list `[1,2,3]` Thus, if you _modify_ the object attached to `A` or `B`,  the other sticky note will reflect the modification. Then when you reassign `A = [5,6]`, you remove the `A` variable sticky note from `[1,2,3]` and place it on the list `[5,6]`. Then the behavior you are seeing hopefully makes a bit more sense. Variables are just labels in Python.

Answer (score 3):

Your first understanding was correct. When you do

```
B = A
```

you now have two names pointing to the same object in memory.

Your misunderstanding is what happens when you do

```
A = [5, 6]
```

This doesn't copy `[5, 6]` to that location in memory. It allocates a new list `[5, 6]` and then changes the name `A` to point to this. But `B` still points to the same list that it pointed to before.

Basically, every time you do

```
A = <something>
```

you're changing where `A` points, not changing the thing that it points to.

Answer (score 0):

Lists are objects and therefore 'call-by-reference'. When you write `B=A` you'll get a reference (c-pointer) on the object behind A (not A itself!), so basically, as your code is telling you already, `A is B == True`. The reference is not on A but on the object that A points to, so if you change A to `A = [5,6]` the interpreter will notice that you've got another reference (B) on the old list and will keep that reference and the list (else it would land in the garbage collector). It'll only change the adress stored in A.

If you then, however, reassing `B=A`, B will be `[5,6]`.

Answer (score 0):

you assign new obj to a at second time

```
>>> 
>>> a= [1,2,3]
>>> id(a)
4353139632
>>> b = a
>>> id(b)
4353139632
>>> a= [4,5]
>>> id(a)
4353139776
>>> id(b)
4353139632
```

Answer (score 0):

Lists, tuples, and objects are ***referenced*** in Python. You can see these variable names as pointers in C. So, A is a *pointer* to some location, storing an array, when you did `B = A` you copied the ***reference*** to that location ( the address ) to B.

So, when you changed contents at that location, *via A*, then consequently, answer would be what that is at that memory location, whether you access it via A or B.

However, if you would like to *copy the elements*, you can use

```
B = [i for i in A]
```

or something like that.

and when you assigned some other value to A, `A = [5,6]`, the reference at A is now pointing to some *other* memory location, and that at B to the original location, so B stays same.